cannot find name SentrySibling
I have a React application wrapped with Capacitor. trying to install sentry while following the "getting started" pages.
It says to do:
npm install --save @sentry/capacitor @sentry/react@^7
and then copy paste this code to my app:
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/capacitor';
import * as SentryReact from '@sentry/react';

Sentry.init({
    dsn:"https://xxxxxxxxx.ingest.us.sentry.io/xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    integrations: [
      SentrySibling.browserTracingIntegration(),
      new SentryReact.BrowserTracing({
      // Set 'tracePropagationTargets' to control for which URLs distributed 
         tracing should be enabled
     tracePropagationTargets: ["localhost",/^https:\/\/yourserver\.io\/api/],
     }),
     new SentryReact.Replay(),
   ],
    // Tracing
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0, //  Capture 100% of the transactions
   // Session Replay
   replaysSessionSampleRate: 0.1, // This sets the sample rate at 10%. You 
   may want to change it to 100% while in development and then sample at a 
   lower rate in production.
   replaysOnErrorSampleRate: 1.0, // If you're not already sampling the 
   entire session, change the sample rate to 100% when sampling sessions 
   where errors occur.
   },
   // Forward the init method from @sentry/react
   SentryReact.init
);

Added an image to make it clear:

And this is what I see in my IDE:

Problems:

new SentryReact.BrowserTracing is deprecated
SentrySibling has no import (and couldn't find it anywhere in documentation)
Replay is deprecated.

What am I missing?

The BrowserTracing integration in @sentry/react has been deprecated in favor of Tracing or BrowserTracing from @sentry/tracing.
Could you please try below code.
import { init as sentryInit } from '@sentry/capacitor';
import { BrowserTracing } from '@sentry/tracing';
import { Replay } from '@sentry/react';

sentryInit({
  dsn: "https://xxxxxxxxx.ingest.us.sentry.io/xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  integrations: [
    new BrowserTracing({
      tracePropagationTargets: ["localhost", /^https:\/\/yourserver\.io\/api/],
    }),
    new Replay(),
  ],
  tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
  replaysSessionSampleRate: 0.1,
  replaysOnErrorSampleRate: 1.0,
});

Also try the below code to install the correct Sentry packages -
npm install @sentry/capacitor @sentry/tracing @sentry/react


Thank you, but it still says  BrowserTracing is deprecated event from '@sentry/tracing'

Looks like there is lots of depression happens, BrowserTracing() has replaced with browserTracingIntegration() and  new Replay() replased with replayIntegration() , kindly follow the docs - https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/migration/v7-to-v8/v7-deprecations/
